# When the prompt "Did you find anything..." runs, the prompt text contains "false" instead of actual text

Tags: javascript, prompt

```js
    var route = 2; var name = prompt("'What is your name soldier?'");

 if(route === 2) {
  if (prompt ("Well,. Did you find anything unusual out on your patrol? (Lie or truth?)".length === 3)) {
  alert("'No sir, nothing unusual.' you say.")
 }
 else
  alert("'Well, I did find a warehouse sir. It was emitting a strange sound, but I thought nothing of it.' you say")
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (prompt ("Well,. Did you find anything unusual out on your patrol? (Lie or truth?)".length === 3)) {
```

It is using a boolean for the value to `prompt()` - e.g. if (prompt(*string length* ===3) {... Because the property [.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) is being accessed on the string passed to [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), instead of the return value from the prompt.

To check the length of the string entered by the user, move one of the parentheses before the `.length` property is accessed, like this:

```
if (prompt ("Well,. Did you find anything unusual out on your patrol? (Lie or truth?)").length === 3) {
```

Try it out in this snippet (click the button labeled *Run code Snippet*):

```js
 var route = 2; var name = prompt("'What is your name soldier?'");

 if(route === 2) {
  if (prompt ("Well,. Did you find anything unusual out on your patrol? (Lie or truth?)").length === 3) {
  alert("'No sir, nothing unusual.' you say.")
 }
 else
  alert("'Well, I did find a warehouse sir. It was emitting a strange sound, but I thought nothing of it.' you say")
 }
```

Comment: Yea, i figured that out soon after I posted the question... But thanks for the help anyways!